# how to convert sqlcommand type to String type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to fetch value from the first row and first column.  After fetching I need to convert that value to a string. Please help me with the conversion.

Here is my current code:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=MIN-MAK MRO;Trusted_Connection=true";
conn.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Top 1 FirstName FROM HistoryReport ", conn);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to fetch that single value? If so see `.ExecuteScalar()` - also as there is no `order by` in your statement the value you get is effectively a random one from the column.

Comment: iam asking how to convert that single value i fetched to string type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this -

```
string getValue = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

**Note:** If there are no rows `.ExecuteScalar()` will return `null`

Comment: hi abhishek the code u told was worked thanks for that. i had small doubt if i need to change the value to DateTime datatype how i need to change my code

Answer (score 0):

The result from a query with a single result is returned as bare `Object`. To safely convert it to string, you need to first check it against both `DBNull.Value` and against null, before performing `ToString()` on it.

```
public static String SafeGetString(Object databaseResult)
{
    if (databaseResult == DBNull.Value || databaseResult == null)
        return null;
    return databaseResult.ToString();
}
```